# Hide top bar works incorrect

Tags: workspaces, top-bar

[image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr7sD.png)

How to fix? Folder and file climb to top bar.
Disabling the extension helps to solve the problem, but I would like it to work as it should.
extension = Hide top bar https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/

Sorry for my English

Comment: Version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Gnome 3.28

Comment: Please include all information that is needed or can help to answer the question in the body of your question. Use "edit" under your question. Be also clear. You refer to "the extension" without specifying it.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported on GitHub and there is a solution [here](https://github.com/mlutfy/hidetopbar/issues/190)